# How do I include Table of Contents in the automatic table of contents?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm translating a Russian document (word 2007) in which the automatic table of contents references itself: it says "Table of Contents........3".

When I try to create an automatic TOC in my file translated into English, it does not reference itself. What do I do to make it include itself?

When I enable Structure View mode and set the phrase "Table of Contents" to Level 1, my whole automatic TOC for some reason changes its formatting radically, so I revert back..

I need "TABLE OF CONTENTS" to be automatically included before "ABBREVIATIONS" there:

> [image]

Comment: What if you copy format from ABBREVIATIONS header to TABLE OF CONTENTS header and refresh TOC?

Comment: @endrju - thank you! It worked! I'd like to know what exactly **made** it work.

Comment: I don't know why TOC broke after you changed "Table of Contents" to level 1, but this TOC may be based on styles (a style can have a level assigned in the TOC definition) and because ABBREVIATIONS is already in the TOC then setting another header to the same style works.